# Unable to proceed with tracking after refreshing in SCORM 2004 course on pop-up browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, scorm, scorm2004

I've created a SCORM 2004 package and launched it in a SCORM LMS. The LMS opens the course up as a pop-up window and runs like it should on normal usage.

Problem comes when all data tracking are lost when some of our learners refresh their browsers midway while taking the course. All the quizzes and progress are not tracked when F5 or reload is clicked.

How do i fix this or is this a normal behavior in SCORM environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for the SCORM course to save the tracking data mid way through using [Commit](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/).

Generally though, refreshing the page during the course is a bad idea. It's like closing and re-opening Word without saving in the middle of writing a document. You should ask your learners not to do that.

Comment: Don't forget to set `cmi.exit` to `"suspend"` in your beforeunload event - and handle when `cmi.entry` is set to `"resume"` to put everything back where it should be.